# OpenJPA: Bottleneck Sequence in Bulk Insert

Tags: oracle, jpa, sequence, bulkinsert, openjpa

I use OpenJpa on a WAS 8.0 and a Oracle 11 DB ... (afaik OpenJPA 2.1)
I have a bulk insert with a entity. (300.000)

**Tests:** I save the entitys with id generation from sequence and with a own generated id.

**Result:**

Insert 200.000 Entitys with persist:
With Sequence 2 Minutes and 30 seconds.
With own id 35 seconds.

Insert 500.000 Entitys with persist:
With Sequence 5 Minutes 
With own id 100 seconds.

The problem is that the sequence trigger every insert. But i should use the sequence.

I read something about allowcationsize caches the values in jvm, i think, that is the right way but it is OpenJPA 2.2 (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_2.2.html)

Is there another good way to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to up the size of the [sequence generator allocation size.](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_mapping_sequence.html#jpa_overview_mapping_sequence_seqgen)

Comment: yes, this works fine with OpenJPA 2.3 but i must use 2.1. When i made it in 2.1, jpa made a sequence query for every insert. (In 2.3 not)

Comment: It should work ok 2.1.x also. If not, it must have been fixed and not back ported. You could search https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA for related issues. Good luck!